# How do I test my implementation of LT codes?

Tags: python, testing

Inspired by Nick Johnson's blog [Damn Cool Algorithms: Fountain Codes](http://blog.notdot.net/2012/01/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Fountain-Codes), I decided to have a go at implementing a [Luby Transform (LT) code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luby_transform_code). I just pushed it to [GitHub](https://github.com/alexchamberlain/socket/tree/master/fountain); it is written in Python 3.

I developed it using a very short file consisting of just "hello" and tested on a randomly generated 1MB file. The software seems to encode and decode the file effectively, with only the length of the original file, the blocksize and the droplets shared between the encoder and the decoder.

**The question is, how should I prove this is indeed a faithful implementation of an LT code? How do I prove that the decoding algorithm is efficient?**

It was my intention that used droplets are deleted by Python's counted references system. **How do I check this is indeed occuring?**

Any feedback on the code itself is also welcome, though it may be more appropriate as a comment (rather than an answer) or an issue on GitHub.

Comment: Although [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207101/how-do-you-prove-a-function-works) isn't specific to yours but it might be helpful.

Comment: About the reference count I think you simply can't. First of all the python language is probably well tested, so there shouldn't be many memory leaks. Secondly, it highly depends on the version(a memory leak found in X.Y, would be fixed in next realeases).
Usually you simply take the language as it was "perfect". Except for known bugs I shall say. By the way, even trying to prove something with assembly language wont work, because hardware may have errors so it's a limitation that you can't remove completely.

Comment: @Bakuriu Thanks for your answer. I'm not trying to prove there aren't memory leaks, rather the objects are being deleted when I think they should be.

Comment: Could you please direct me to a place where LT codes are implemented in C? I couldn't find a source in the internet

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to see if the reference counting is working, you can define the `__del__` method in your classes. Be aware that this will prevent the cyclic GC from working on those classes

Another way is to look at changes to the refcount of the class, since each instance holds a reference to the class

```
>>> from sys import getrefcount
>>> class Obj(object):
...  pass
... 
>>> sys.getrefcount(Obj)
5
>>> obj_list=[Obj() for x in range(5)]
>>> sys.getrefcount(Obj)
10
>>> obj_list[:3]=[]
>>> sys.getrefcount(Obj)
7
```